# multiple transition runs instantly even though transition-duration is given

Tags: javascript, css

the first transition runs instantly and the second one runs perfect. I been trying to run it at the same time with the transition-duration. Some help would be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Scroll(){
        var top = document.getElementById('header');
        var ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        document.getElementById('color-change-on-scroll').innerHTML=ypos;
        if(ypos > 2350) {
            var elem = document.getElementById('homer_pic');
            elem.style.transition="top 1.0s linear 0s"; // runs instantly
            elem.style.top="0px";
            elem.style.transition="opacity 1.0s linear 0s"; // runs perfect
            elem.style.opacity=1;
            document.getElementById('color-change-on-scroll').innerHTML=ypos+" yposhigher then 2350";
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll",Scroll);
</script>

#homer_pic{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 33.333333%;
    background-color:  #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 120px; 
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    top:100px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time you post a question please provide all relevant parts of your code to make it a [minimal, complete and verifiable  example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (HTML is missing here). This will increase the chance that someone can help you.

Comment: Ah.. i thought it wasnt necessary :| Sorry for the inconvenience. :/

Answer (score 0):

Each element can only have one CSS transition property.

```
elem.style.transition="top 1.0s linear 0s"; // runs instantly
elem.style.top="0px";
elem.style.transition="opacity 1.0s linear 0s"; // runs perfect
elem.style.opacity=1;
```

The second transition definition overrides the first one. That's why it seems to *run instantly*. To transition multiple properties on the same element you'd have to do it like this:

```
elem.style.transition = "top 1.0s linear 0s, opacity 1.0s linear 0s";
elem.style.top = "0px";
elem.style.opacity = 1;
```

```js
function Scroll() {
  var top = document.getElementById('header');
  var ypos = window.pageYOffset;
  document.getElementById('color-change-on-scroll').innerHTML = ypos;
  if (ypos > 50) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('homer_pic');
    elem.style.transition = "top 1.0s linear 0s, opacity 1.0s linear 0s";
    elem.style.top = "0px";
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById('color-change-on-scroll').innerHTML = ypos + " yposhigher then 50";
  } else {}
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll);
```

```css
body {
  height: 400px;
}

#homer_pic {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 33.333333%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="homer_pic">
  Pic
</div>
<div style="position: fixed" id="color-change-on-scroll">
  0
</div>
```

Comment: Ah !! Its alive !! :D Thanks a lot Mr Marvin :) :)

Comment: You are welcome. Would be cool if you could accept the answer then with the little check under the vote buttons on the left :)